# select all the entries in a checkedTreeselectionDialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.CheckedTreeSelectionDialog, to display a list of values. I want to select(check) all the values by default. Can you please let me know how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set which nodes are checked initially (on dialog creation), by using the [setInitialElementSelections](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/SelectionDialog.html#setInitialElementSelections%28java.util.List%29) method.

```
CheckedTreeSelectionDialog dlg = new CheckedTreeSelectionDialog(shell, 
    new cLabelProvider(), 
    new cContentProvider());
dlg.setInput(model);
dlg.setInitialElementSelections(model.getAllElements());
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that you do your
`dlg.setInitialElementSelections(model.getAllElements());`
*before* you open your dialog: 
`dlg.open();` because otherwise it won't work.