# CheckedTreeSelectionDialog check elements initially

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, swt

I am using a **CheckedTreeSelectionDialog** and I want to select initially some items.

How do I use the method **setInitialSelections** to select children (level2 items) and not level1.

```
CheckedTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new CheckedTreeSelectionDialog(
    this.containerComposite.getShell(), new myLabelProvider(), new
    myContentProvider());

dialog.setContainerMode(true);
dialog.setInput(new MyModel());

Parent p = new Parent("I am a parent");
p.getChildren.add(new Child("I am a child"));
dialog.setInitialSelection(p);
```

The child is not selected when containerMode is false and when is true like the example it selects all the children.

Comment: Not used it but looking at the API and your sample code, have you tried just passing a reference to the Child into the setInitialSelection method?

Comment: i tried and the children do not get selected, but even if they did some parents may have the same children how can it distinguise? In some way i shouldnt give parent/child path?

Comment: Please, post the contents of the class `myContentProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the method [`SelectionDialog#setInitialElementSelections(List elements)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/SelectionDialog.html#setInitialElementSelections%28java.util.List%29) and pass the elements you want to be selected in a `List`:

```
CheckedTreeSelectionDialog dialog = new CheckedTreeSelectionDialog(
this.containerComposite.getShell(), new myLabelProvider(), new myContentProvider());

dialog.setContainerMode(true);
dialog.setInput(new MyModel());

List<Child> list = new ArrayList<Child>();

/* fill your list */

dialog.setInitialElementSelections(list);
```

Comment: i tried and the children do not get selected, but even if they did some parents may have the same children how can it distinguise? In some way i shouldnt give parent/child path to selecT?

Comment: @user847988 How can they have the same children? Then it wouldn't be a tree but a graph...

Comment: @user847988 BTW: I found a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605308/select-all-the-entries-in-a-checkedtreeselectiondialog) with almost the identical answer and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you do your 
`dialog.setInitialElementSelections(model.getAllElements());`
*before* you open your dialog: `dialog.open();` 
because otherwise it won't work.

I had the same problem - I could only mark the fisrt level element.
The solution was to make sure that these methods are working in the `ITreeContentProvider` implementation class:

```
// this is the object that would get passed into setInput()
private MyModelProvider model; 

@Override
public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) 
    this.model = (MyModelProvider ) newInput;
}

@Override
public Object getParent(Object element) {
    if (element instanceof Child)
        return model.getCategories().get(0);    // I only have one category 
    return null;
}
```